# Paramiko execute command on psql

Tags: python, shell, ssh, psql, paramiko

Using Paramiko I'm creating an ssh to that connects to my remote machine, then I call exec_command to run the following:

```
psql usera
```

Normally `exec_command` returns a tuple of `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`. Therefore, I use the `stdin` to write `CREATE DATABASE X` with `'\n'` at the end to simulate the enter button. The command takes a lot of time to the extent that it looks like its stuck.

Here is my code:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = self.ssh.exec_command('psql usera')
print('executed')
print(stdin)
print(stdout)
print(stderr)
for err in stderr:
    print(err)
for std in stdout:
    print(std)
stdin.write('CREATE DATABASE ' + db_name + ';\n')
```

This code will print the following:

```
executed
<paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 2 (open) window=2097152 -> <paramik
o.Transport at 0x36a29b0 (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 3 open channel(s
))>>>
<paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 2 (open) window=2097152 -> <paramik
o.Transport at 0x36a29b0 (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 3 open channel(s
))>>>
<paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 2 (open) window=2097152 -> <paramik
o.Transport at 0x36a29b0 (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 3 open channel(s
))>>>
2018-12-12 19:22:39; DEBUG; EOF in transport thread
```

Which means that the code doesn't execute `stdin.write()`. Is this the proper way to launch commands, and launch commands on a prompt?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl ,it gets stuck after:     stdin, stdout, stderr = self.ssh.exec_command('psql usera')

Comment: well this :         stdin, stdout, stderr = self.ssh.exec_command('psql usera')
        print('executed !')
        print(stdin)
        print(stdout)
        print(stderr)
        for err in stderr:
            self.logger.error(err)
        for std in stdout:
            print(std)
        print('ex')
        print('2')

will show =>
executed !

<paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 2 (open) window=2097152 -> <paramik
o.Transport at 0x36a29b0 (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 3 open channel(s
))>>>

for the 3 concurent prints.

Comment: ok, it's done !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to read a command output before you send the SQL command. Your loops wait for the command to finish, what it never does, as it keeps waiting for an input. That's a deadlock.

It has to be the other way around:

```
stdin.write('CREATE DATABASE ' + db_name + ';\n')
for err in stderr:
    print(err)
for std in stdout:
    print(std)
```

While I'm not familiar with `psql` command-line, I'm pretty sure that the above code will hang too, as after `CREATE DATABASE`, `psql` it will probably keep waiting for another command. You need to add something like `EXIT`. Or call `stdin.close()`.

```
stdin.write('CREATE DATABASE ' + db_name + ';\n')
stdin.close()
for err in stderr:
    print(err)
for std in stdout:
    print(std)
```